# Stopping orphan quartz scheduler

Tags: linux, jakarta-ee, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

I have set up quartz scheduler for my Tomcat server and restarted the server several times.

The scheduler started giving errors of the kind (very often btw - every 30 seconds):

```
DEBUG org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread  - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
log4j:ERROR Error occured while converting date.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.getChars(AbstractStringBuilder.java:328)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.getChars(StringBuffer.java:201)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.ISO8601DateFormat.format(ISO8601DateFormat.java:130)
        at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:316)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.PatternParser$DatePatternConverter.convert(PatternParser.java:444)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.PatternConverter.format(PatternConverter.java:65)
        at org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.format(PatternLayout.java:502)
        at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:302)
        at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:160)
        at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.debug(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:209)
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:268)
```

I think I fixed the problem, but now I face another issue: the first few times I restarted Tomcat, I did not shut down the quartz scheduler. Now I added the following code to my scheduler:

```
public class QuartzListener implements ServletContextListener {
    private Scheduler scheduler;

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        if (scheduler != null) {
            try {
                scheduler.shutdown();
           } catch (SchedulerException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
...
}
```

This seems to be stopping the new quartz instances, but the old ones keep on logging the same old error. So my question is: how do I stop quartz instances that I accidently forgot to stop gracefully via `shutdown()`?

I am running on linux, but I never saw the quartz processes/ deamons when I run `ps aux`, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Are you using the JDBCStore? if yes try to cleanup the tables maybe. You could also enable the MBean and give a look of what is currently running with jconsole for instance

Comment: BTW, you should be using the `org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener` class